# Unable to connect to a Socket Based Server on AWS

Tags: java, sockets, amazon-web-services

Update One: Through use of a [TCP port checker](http://www.infobyip.com/tcpportchecker.php), I was able to verify that the port 8080 on the AWS instance is active and accepting connections.
This means that the port is likely not being bound properly somehow, will update back if I manage to resolve this issue.
Additionally, through use of the AWS server instance logs, under /var/log/nginx/error.log are entries that suggest the connection is being refused, despite the unrestricted access protocols.

---

I have a Socket Based Server that runs completely fine on localhost. I start the server, then instance client calls, and behaviour is as desired and expected; the server returns "Hello World" to the client and terminates the connection.
However, if I upload the server to AWS and host it as a Java application, I cannot establish a connection and reproduce the behaviour of the localhost service.

---

HelloWorldServer:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class NetMiddlewareServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int portNumber = 8080;
        while(true){
            try ( 
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            PrintWriter out =
                new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        ) {

            System.out.println("Test");
            String inputLine, outputLine;

            // Initiate conversation with client
            outputLine = "Hello World";
            out.println(outputLine);

            clientSocket.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception caught when trying to listen on port "
                + portNumber + " or listening for a connection");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        }
}
```

---

HelloWorldClient:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class KKPClient {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String hostName = "localhost";
    int portNumber = 8080;

    try (
        Socket hwSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(hwSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(hwSocket.getInputStream()));
    ) {
        BufferedReader stdIn =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String fromServer;

        while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Server: " + fromServer);
        }

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host " + hostName);
        System.exit(1);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to " +
            hostName);
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

}

---

The above code works completely fine locally, however uploading the Server to AWS and changing the hostName leads to errors, and I believe this is where the problem lies.
The IP address for the server instance for example, 52.214.166.199, does not connect and an IOException is thrown when trying to declare the Socket hwSocket. No input is returned as the Socket is not properly created, and so the Hello World message is not received.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Socket is not connected: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
at kkpclient.KKPClient.main(hwClient.java:19)
C:\Users\[me]\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
```

Comment: Did you open port in AWS Security Group assigned to VM instance where you host server?

Comment: @MaximDobryakov Security protocols currently allow any and all inbound/outbound traffic.

Comment: FYI: Full text of `IOException` can help to investigate problem.

Comment: @MaximDobryakov I don't know about that, as the stack trace claims that the socket isn't connected, which is peculiar given that the IP is correct and the security protocols should allow for connection. Stack trace placed in OP anyway for you to have a look at should you like.